# Plugin where one can make shapefile (polygon) with help of coordinate values

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, qgis-plugins, polygon-creation, vector-layer

Is there any plugins or method where one can easily make shapefile (polygon) with the help of coordinate values?

You can find in the attached file.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to create polygons from points?

Comment: yes.
single point at a time is possible that i know it, i was asking that is there any possibility with these points that I showed above using plugins and functionality  make shapefile (point or polygon) at a time.

Comment: That text starting "MultiPolygon" with coordinates in round brackets (parentheses) looks like the "WKT" (Well-Known Text) format. Look for a way to read WKT data into QGIS and you should have the solution.

Comment: As said by Spacedman this look like WKT. Did you know in witch CRS these coordinate are ?

Comment: The coordinate system values are from ESRI:102004